# How to pass selected option using knockout to an observable array

Tags: javascript, select, knockout.js, observable

I am trying to pass the selected value of a drop down list to my view model using knockout js.

`<select class="form-control" style="width:auto" data-bind="options: clients, optionsCaption: 'Choose...', optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'value', value: 'selectedCustomer'"></select>`

In my view model, I have declared a ko observable to store the selected value:

`self.selectedCustomer = ko.observableArray([]);`

The variable is not getting populated when I select a value. Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two issues with the code:

You're binding the value to an `observableArray`, but the selected option would be a single customer so `observable` should be used instead.

The value (`value: 'selectedCustomer'`) should also not be wrapped in single quotes because then you're effectively trying to bind to a string rather than the observable.

Try the below:

```
<select class="form-control" style="width:auto" data-bind="options: clients, optionsCaption: 'Choose...', optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'value', value: selectedCustomer"></select>
```

Then in the view model:

```
self.selectedCustomer = ko.observable();
```